# How to structure form data within MongoDB (Python/Flask)

Tags: python, html, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am having trouble structuring my data within MongoDB from user forms.

My ideal document structure is this:

[image]

As you can see the ingredients are within an array that would be iterable.

However I cannot work out a way when submitting my form to do this. My form for the ingredients section looks like this:

```html
 <h4>Ingredients</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input id="ingredients_1_name" name="ingredients_name_1" type="text" class="validate" required>
                <label for="ingredients_1_name">Ingredient</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s3">
                <input id="ingredients_1_quantity" name="ingredients_quantity_1" type="text" class="validate" required>
                <label for="ingredients_1_quantity">Quantity</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s3">
                <input id="ingredients_1_unit" name="ingredients_unit_1" type="text" class="validate" required>
                <label for="ingredients_1_unit">Unit</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The user is able to press a JavaScript button that adds a new row with the name "ingredients_2_name" and so on. This leads to a very unstructured DB:

[image]

This is obviously a mess which when it comes to using the data requires an unnecessary amount of manipulation.

I can't seem to find any information online about how to send data from a HTML form to MongoDB in a defined way.

Currently on form submission, the view looks like this:

```js
@app.route('/insert_recipe/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def insert_recipe():
    """
    This function is called when a user clicks the submit button on the add
    recipe form. Uses the insert_one() method to add to the recipes document.
    """
    recipes = mongo.db.recipes
    dictionary = recipes.insert_one(request.form.to_dict())
    return redirect(url_for("get_recipes"))
```

This simply takes the input names as keys and the user input as values.

Is anyone able to describe how I am able to store form data within MongoDB in a structured way?

Answer (score 0):

What you require is to convert a plain HTML-form-post request into a JSON-like structure without any data manipulations. I highly doubt that it's even possible, because JSON-objects use **nested** data and a key/index approach to access it and HTML-form-post data is **flat** and follows unique-id-approach to access it's data. I can see 2 possible solutions:

1. Use serialization library WTForms which will do python-data -> html-form -> python-data conversion for you and you wouldn't have to do *an unnecessary amount of manipulation* by yourself.
2. Make a webpage (a front-end) post request for you as a JSON-object.